# Incompatible with Google Play services and Firebase version not working

Tags: java, android, cordova

I used cordova google plus login and firebase messaging.
cordova packages are like follow.

```
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "5.3.1",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^1.1.4"
```

But google plus login not working.
I think it's android package incompatible.

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.+"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to used same package version google play service and firebase service package like that.

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0"
```

Comment: sir you can make changes in her questions to tell her